# Why is adjoining an identity to semigroup a reflection?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading the book *The Joy of Cats*, and I'm confused about this example from 4.17:

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be $\mathbf{Sgr}$, the subcategory of $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{Mon}$ consisting of semigroups, then for each semigroup, the extension that adjoins to it a new identity element is an $\mathbf{A}$-reflection.

If I'm understanding the concepts correctly, I think this means that for any semigroup homomorphism $f: B \to A'$, for monoid $A'$, this factors (uniquely) as $r\circ f: B\to A\to A'$, where $r: B\to A$ is the map described above, and $f':A\to A'$ is a monoid homomorphism. Suppose $B = A' = (\mathbb{N}, \times)$, and $f$ is the semigroup (but not monoid) homomorphism that takes all elements to $0$, then we can first adjoin an element to $B$, and then find a monoid homomorphism from this monoid to $A'$.

What I'm confused about is the following: If $(\mathbb{N},\times)$ is already a monoid, why is adjoining an identity not simply the identity, i.e. leaving everything unchanged? It cannot be, but I fail to see why.

Comment: Take a monoid $M$. Let $*$ be something not in $M$. Consider $M'=M\cup\{*\}$ and define a multiplication on $M'$ by letting $a*=*a=a$ for all $a\in M'$, and $ab$ to be the same as multiplication in $M$ if $a,b\in M$. This is the monoid you get when you adjoin a unit to $M$, even if $M$ already has a unit. Note that the old unit of $M$ is not a unit for $M'$, since $1*\neq *$. So you are *forcing* this to be a new monoid, and not the one you already had. The process isn't "find me the smallest monoid that contains $M$", it's "do *these things* to $M$ to get a monoid that contains $M$."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks a lot for clearing away my confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor from $\mathsf{Semigroup}$ to $\mathsf{Monoid}$ that is the adjoint of the forgetful functor is the "adjoin a unity (even if there already is one)" functor: given a semigroup $S$, let $*$ be something not in $S$. Define the semigroup $S^1$ to be the semigroup with underlying set $S\cup\{*\}$, and multiplication $\cdot$ given by
$$a\cdot b=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
ab &\text{if }a,b\in S\\
a&\text{if }b=*\\
b&\text{if }a=*.
\end{array}\right.$$
The semigroup map from $S$ to $S^1$ is just the natural inclusion of $S$ into $S\cup\{*\}$. This is your functor.

Note that you aren't trying to find a "least monoid that contains $S$". You are explicitly *adjoining* an identity to $S$. If $S$ already happened to have an identity, $1$, that doesn't matter; you are adding a new element, and this new element is the identity of $S'$. The old  identity $1$ is no longer an identity, since by definition $1\cdot * = 1$, and not $*$.

This is analogous to the fact that a monoid may have a subsemigroup that is a monoid but that is not a submonoid. For example, in the multiplicative monoid of $2\times 2$ matrices with real coefficients, the matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ are a subsemigroup which is a monoid (that is, which has an identity), but it is not a submonoid of the $2\times 2$ matrices. Likewise, once you adjoin an identity to $(\mathbb{N},\times)$, you get a new monoid $(\mathbb{N}^1,\times')$ which contains $\mathbb{N}$ as a subsemigroup-which-is-a-monoid, though it is not a submonoid.

Comment: I suggest to change the notation from $S^1$ (which is already overloaded) to something else.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I had different notation, but as far as I know this is in fact the *standard* notation for that adjunction. So no.

Comment: Ok. Too bad. I can list 3 different meanings of $S^1$ then.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. So can I; but it is fairly standard.